# Casting Error When using tasks in C# Windows Forms Webrowser

Tags: c#, multithreading, casting

I keep getting a casting error when calling a method that then calls a thread that sleeps for a period of time then returns and continues on the original thread. I use the await command to pause the main thread until the sleep thread returns. I can't figure it out but if I avoid the threading then the casting error vanishes.? Very weird to me but i'm new to multithreading. The error occurs in the login method where I check this (webBrowser1.Document != null && webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("login_password") != null)    Even if I remove this if statement the very next statement regardless of what it is throws the same error.

```
 private async void main() {
        Console.WriteLine("Main");
        Task generatePassTask = new Task(generatePass);
        Task loginControllerTask = new Task(loginController);
        Task balanceControllerTask = new Task(balanceController);
        //Starts delay and waits for completion.
        generatePassTask.Start();
        await generatePassTask;

        loginControllerTask.Start();
        await loginControllerTask;

        balanceControllerTask.Start();
        await balanceControllerTask;


    }

    private async void loginController() {
        Console.WriteLine("loginController");
        Task resetDelayTask = new Task(resetDelay);

        //Starts delay and waits for completion.
        resetDelayTask.Start();
        await resetDelayTask;

        Task loginTask = new Task(login);

        //Starts delay and waits for completion.
        loginTask.Start();
        await loginTask;


        //Calls login method once delay has completed.
        //login();
    }
    private void login() {
        Console.WriteLine("login");
        if (webBrowser1.Document != null && webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("login_password") != null)
        {
            webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("login_password").SetAttribute("value", pass);
            HtmlElementCollection elems = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("Button");
            foreach (HtmlElement elem in elems)
            {
                string htmlStr = elem.InnerHtml;
                if (htmlStr != null && htmlStr.Length != 0 && htmlStr.Equals("<i class=\"fa fa-arrow-right text-muted\"></i>"))
                {
                    elem.InvokeMember("Click");
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            loginController();
        }
    }

    //Called after logout to sync worker and ui before next login. 
    private static void resetDelay()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("resetDelay");
        Thread.Sleep(1400);
    }
```

Any help would be awesome!!! I've been stuck on this for hours.

Comment: Casting has nothing to do with multithreading. The code though is weird - why are you creating cold tasks? Tasks aren't threads so there is no point at all in creating a task and calling `.Start()` instead of `Task.Run`

Comment: Sorry didn't include the task method one sec.

Comment: *Don't* use `Task.Start`. There is no point in doing so. Use Task.Run if you have to. You are using 3 lines when only 1 is needed and make the code *very* convoluted. What are you trying to do anyway?

Comment: I'm trying to make an app that will create 800 accounts on my web app. Would .Run solve the casting problem or even wait for the process to be done before moving on?

Comment: PS `async void` is only meant for event handlers, because it *can't* be awaited. Your `loginController` method could still be running when the objects it needs are already disposed

Comment: Another serious problem - resetDelay is *blocking*. Use `await Task.Delay(1400);` instead.

Comment: Ok, but the editor won't allow me to remove the void

Comment: If you want to add 800 users, why don't you do that directly in the database? Anyway, if you want to post a form 800 times, use HttpClient and send 800 post requests. There is no point in using a browser for this. You can capture the required POST request with Fiddler

Comment: If you don't know that the correct syntax is `async Task`, you should start with a tutorial on `async/await`. This code has far too many basic mistakes

Comment: the main reason I'm not entering directly is because I want proof the web app ui works flawlessly. Plus I thought why not try something new as well

Comment: HttpClient uses only asynchronous methods. You can check the response to check that creation worked. What you describe is no different than scraping, which *doesn't* require a browser

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that an error is thrown when you try to access you UI ( webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("login_password") ) inside another Task. 
Indeed, your UI is executed inside your main thread...

Try to pass the login and the password as parameters to your method. It will normally work.

Also, I don't know the business of your application but I find it very weird to invoke the "Click" member of your button to execute an action...

Hope I could help !

Comment: The invoke "Click" is the only way I could figure out how to send a click to my web apps html button

Comment: @AngryChicken form buttons result in a POST request that contains the form's fields in the body

Comment: I'm not doing this within the app itself so I don't have access to the internals such as the POST of the application. I'm acting as if this is an independent web browser on someone computer